# Multiply keras loss functions by constant

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Is it possible to symbolically multiply a built-in keras loss function by a constant? For example if I want a linear combination of the losses of two outputs.

I could write a custom loss function, but will it not get compiled since it's python code, not symbolic Keras? I'm looking for a way to do it in pure Keras (or TF)

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely possible. However, there are multiple ways of going about this, depending on exactly what you want to achieve. Could you perhaps elaborate your question? If your model yields 2 outputs, you can supply a list of losses and optionally provide weights, e.g. `loss_weights=[1., 0.2]`. See https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models for more information.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find that in a list of arguments to compile() so I assumed it wasn't there!

Comment: You're welcome! I added my comment as a full answer below. If it answered your question satisfactorily, please accept :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your model yields multiple outputs, you can assign a loss function for each output by supplying a list of [Keras losses](https://keras.io/losses/) to the `loss` argument of the model's `compile` method. For example, if your model is of the form

```
model = Model(inputs=[input_a, input_b], outputs=[output_a, output_b])
```

You can compile it like so:

```
model.compile(
    optimizer='rmsprop',
    loss=['binary_crossentropy', 'mean_squared_error'],
    loss_weights=[1., 0.2]
)
```

This will assign a binary cross-entropy loss to output `output_a` and a mean squared error loss to `output_b`. The loss that ends up being minimized will be a weighted sum of these losses, with the weights specified in `loss_weights`.

Alternatively, if the output layers are named, you can also specify the `loss` and `loss_weights` with dicts with the output layer name as keys. This might help remove ambiguity about which loss and weights are assigned to which outputs.

See https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models for further information.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a single loss function and apply combo loss within itself.

Like for example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# model = your_model
...

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    l_1 = 0.6
    l_2 = 0.4
    mae = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
    mse = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
    loss_mae = mae(y_true , y_pred)
    loss_mse = mse(y_true , y_pred)
    total_loss = l_1*loss_mae + l_2*loss_mse
    return total_loss


model.compile(loss=custom_loss, 
              optimizer='Adam')

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS)
```

This example uses weighted loss of MAE and MSE. You can do all sorts of things with loss function to attain a desired objective!